# Ввод числа с плавающей запятой

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, html5

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="number"  required="" min=0 step="0.01" >
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```

Делаю вывод валюты с учетом копеек, тоисть последних 2 знаков после запятой (нужно с точкой или запятой). В хроме все отрабатывает отлично например ввожу 5,555 или 5.555 валидация не пускает, в мазиле 5.555 не пускает НО 5,555 щитает валидным. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: К сожалению пока разные браузеры элементы форм с типами ввода HTML5 типа number или datetime выводят по-разному, и это рождает массу проблем. Решение - использовать кастомный элемент ввода.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value,
    y = x[x.length - 1],
    r;
    
    if(y === ','){
      r = x.substring(0,x.length - 1) + '.';
      document.getElementById("myInput").value = r;
    }


}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Возможно, вам подойдет вариант с заменой запятых на точки